# how to send the SharedPreferences values to php file?

Tags: php, android, android-sharedpreferences

what i am basically trying to do is,i am creating a login app,using the firebase i am getting the token of that device and storing it database,while when the app is installed in the device token is stored in the database,here i store the token in SharedPreferences for the later use, and in next activity,i use the username and password from the database, and her also i use the SharedPreferences to store the value for the later use,

i want to store the id of the user who gave the username and password in logging activity in the database equl to the token,so that i can able to know the who's device token is stored in the database, i found a way to do that using php i am able to update the particular user id equal to token colomn,

but my problem is i am not able to send the username,password,token from the android activity to php file,but i can able fetch the username,password,token from the SharedPreferences,using the toast i can able to see that,but not able to send them to php file.

my question is how to send the SharedPreferences value to php file?

my android code

```
    package com.example.calenderscheduler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Reg_Token_Id extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Name, Password, Token;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("identifier", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Name = mPrefs.getString("Name", null);
        Password = mPrefs.getString("Password", null);
        Token = mPrefs.getString("Token", null);

        Toast.makeText(Reg_Token_Id.this , " token"+Token , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SendDeviceDetails b =new SendDeviceDetails();
        b.execute(Name,Password,Token);

    }


      class SendDeviceDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String data = "";
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String Token = params[2];
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/Scheduler/register_token_userId.php");
                String urlParams = "Name=" + name + "Password=" + password+ "Token=" + Token;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
                    data += (char) tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my php file to get the name,password,token

```
    <?php
 require "init.php";

    $Token = $_POST["Token"];
    $Name = $_POST["Name"];
   $Password = $_POST["Password"];
    $user_id;
    $Token_id;

    // $Token = "fFQU08fqp98:APA91bGbLgJslCw8nN7NxvQnAV_Xz3RsRS76cn8DA2aysbVzG35yJZ9poCaxy9KkZ7SDm2ZhuhxVXJSv9POI5uSmFYZrkZ8kD79XmSP-0qAlafbyWM1gG9JW_7vdOTb-tSDitIXABDEK";  
    // $Name =  "rajesh";
     //$Password ="1995";


    $Sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` 
        WHERE `name`='".$Name."' AND 
        `password`='".$Password."';";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $Sql1);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
     $user_id =  $row['id']; 


    }

     $Sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `user` 
        WHERE `Token`='".$Token."'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $Sql2);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
     $Token_id =  $row['id']; 

    }



        $sql6 =  "UPDATE user SET Employeeid = '".$user_id."'  WHERE id =  " . $Token_id. " ";  
        $result6 = mysqli_query($con, $sql6); 

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

[image: this is my table to store the id]

by giving the name,passwod,token by giving manually i can able to store the id equal to token,but not able to recieve them from android activity.

can any one help me to fithis issue!please!

Comment: Which request method you used POST or GET?

Comment: POST @ Bhavya!i dont understand what error i had made!

Comment: please make a change String variable Naming Convention.

Comment: i have changed it but not working

Comment: Add request method type in code.
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

Answer (score 0):

Set which request method you uses.
Like this way,

```
  HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: i gave the the line below the line  HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); but showing error in setRequestMethod

Comment: like this
Error:(55, 34) error: non-static method setRequestMethod(String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: no there is no error,but the id is not inserted in the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165803/discussion-between-bhavya-gandhi-and-selva-surya).

Answer (score 0):

the error was due to the & ,i forget to use them in between the String urlParams!

error code

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/Scheduler/register_token_userId.php");
            String urlParams = "Name=" + name + "Password=" + password+ "Token=" + Token;
```

correct code

```
 URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/Scheduler/register_token_userId.php");
            String urlParams = "Name="+name+"&Password="+password+"&Token="+token;
```

Comment: Error was not in space but you forgot you add & before parameter name.